# SAS - How to let array do loop output only once?

Tags: loops, sas

The follow code with the do loop creates repeated outputs if '3320' or '3321' appears more than once in following columns. My question is how do I use a do loop w/o it outputting repeated times? The commented out OR statements solves this problem, but it's not efficient given a bigger list of variables.

```
options obs = 1000;
data NIS_2013.PARKINSONS;
 set NIS_2013.NIS_2013_CORE;
 array DX (25) $ dx1--dx25;
 do i = 1 to 25;
  if DX(i) IN ('3320', '3321') then output;
 end;
run;


/* if DX1 IN ('3320', '3321')
OR DX2 IN ('3320', '3321')
OR DX3 IN ('3320', '3321')
OR DX4 IN ('3320', '3321')
... */
```

Comment: Are you only searching for those two diagnoses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the OUTPUT from the loop. Instead create a flag that you then use to output the record.

If you're only searching for those two codes, I would suggest using WHICHC instead to search the array. I've included it in the code below but left it commented out.

```
options obs = 1000;
data NIS_2013.PARKINSONS;
set NIS_2013.NIS_2013_CORE;
array DX (25) $ dx1--dx25;
flag_parkinson=0;
do i = 1 to 25;
   if DX(i) IN ('3320', '3321') then flag_parkinson=1;
end;

if flag_parkinson=1 then output;

*x = whichc('3320', of dx(*)) + whichc('3321', of dx(*));
*if x>0 then output;

run;
```

Comment: Works, but it has to go through the data twice. Is there a way to make it sweep the data just once?

Comment: How is it going through the data twice?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it doesn't. Thanks for the tip! Btw, is there another way to do it using the continue; statement?

Comment: That makes no sense. Why would you use continue here?

Comment: I mean, if there are many iterations, is there a way to flag as soon as it sees the first true DX(i) IN ('3320', '3321') and move on to the next row/observation?

Comment: Did you look at the WHICHC option? Why loop at all?